# finding groups that meet a condition in pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

This is my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':list('xxxyyzz'), 'b':[10,20,30,5,3,1,2]})
```

I group them:

```
groups = df.groupby('a')
```

I want to print the groups that has at least one `b` above 20. In this case I want to print `x`.
This is my desired outcome:

```
x
   a   b
0  x  10
1  x  20
2  x  30
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compare values by [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html), grouping by `a` column like `Series` - `df['a']` and use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html) for test at least one `True` per groups:

```
df1 = df[df['b'].gt(20).groupby(df['a']).transform('any')]
print (df1)
   a   b
0  x  10
1  x  20
2  x  30
```

Comment: When I saw you post I know I need find some other way to achieve it :-)

Answer (score 4):

You could check which values are above `20`, [`GroupBy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) column `a` and `transform` with [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html) to select only those groups with at least one row satisfying the condition:

```
df[df.b.gt(20).groupby(df.a).transform('any')]

   a   b
0  x  10
1  x  20
2  x  30
```

Answer (score 4):

No need `groupby` , just do `isin`

```
df[df.a.isin(df.loc[df.b>20,'a'])]
Out[996]: 
   a   b
0  x  10
1  x  20
2  x  30
```

Comment: I like this answer but the syntax gives me a mild headache...